# Why does the axios always fall in the catch?

Tags: react-native, axios

The axios always falls in cath even with status code 200, and when there is no error it returns:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context.t0.response.data')]

Code:

```
async function handleLogin(){
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('Authorization');
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('ImAuthenticated');
    try {
        const dados = await api.post('/login', { email, password }, { headers: { 'device': 'mobile' } });
        const { hash } = dados.data;
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("Authorization", hash);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("ImAuthenticated", true);
        navigation.navigate('Menu');
        console.log(dados);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("teste");
        if(error.response.data.showIn == "text"){
            setShowInfo(true);
            setEmail('');
            setPass('');
            InEmail.focus();
            if(error.response.data.level == 3){
                setColorInfo(false);
            }else{
                setColorInfo(true);
            }
            setInfoText(error.response.data.error);
        }else{
            setshowBox(true);
            setEmail('');
            setPass('');
            InEmail.focus();
            if(error.response.data.level == 3){
                setcolorBox(false);
            }else{
                setcolorBox(true);
            }
            setboxText(error.response.data.error);
    }
}
    }
```

API AXIOS FILE:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.45:8080'
});

export default api;
```

Comment: Could you share your code in api file?

Comment: yes, in question

Comment: It seems your response has problem. You could move `console.log(dados);` to right below `const dados = await api.post()` to check if dados is valid

Comment: Thank you for your help! In the meantime I've been searching and tried as follows and it worked:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
api.post('/login',
         { email, password },
         { headers: { 'device': 'mobile' } }
).then(dados => {
    // ...
    console.log(dados);
    // ...
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```